# Javascript read session cookies only

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I am wondering if there is an existing trick to filter on the cookies.
I need to get the session cookies only and to discard the other.
The usual way to read cookies using Javascript is:

```
document.cookie
```

However this prints all the cookies, my goal here is to get the session cookies only. I know that unlike "normal" cookies a session cookie has an expiration date.

Does anyone have a code sample to achieve this session cookies extraction?

Best,
Alexandre

Comment: learn about cookies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: Nothing in the cookie specification allows to tag a cookie as "session cookie". It's just a convention used by server-side apps. And you should find endless libraries/functions/snippets in your favourite search engine to read cookies by name.

Comment: @JaromandaX that does not answer my question. There is nothing in this link on how to get the session cookies only. ;)

Comment: sure, but you've shown no knowledge of cookies at all

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I do not know the cookie names that it is the problem, I want to grab the session cookies no matter the domain my JS scripts runs on. I know that it might be a way to capture the cookies with an expiration date, but how?

Comment: The session cookies has not defined an expiration date, it's because if you close the browser it disappears, no matter what date it is. If you define a date, it doesn't converts in a "session" cookie. however, you can't distinct between session cookies and normal cookies in javascript (almost at the time of get it), but you can set it without problems.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly. What I mean is that I can write an app using PHP and store session cookies in a cookie named `JENNIFER`. There are no rules to be enforced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "session cookie" *is* a normal cookie. It may (or may not) have an expiration date but nothing prevents other cookies to have an expiration date as well. The only reliable way to identify a session cookie is if you know its name (this is website-dependent of course, but isn't a problem if this is *your* website).

Also, you have no way of knowing a cookie's expiration date from Javascript.

Now `document.cookie` gives you all cookies as a semi-colon delimited string. You just need to break it down on semi-colons to retrieve the key-value pairs. So here's a sample code to look for a cookie given its name:

```
var getCookie = function(name) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0 ; i < cookies.length ; ++i) {
        var pair = cookies[i].trim().split('=');
        if(pair[0] == name)
            return pair[1];
    }
    return null;
};
```

If you don't know the session cookie's name you're out of luck. Period. You could maybe find clever heuristics to determine which one it is (based on the form of name and/or value), but nothing can tell you exactly for all websites with 100% confidence which cookie is the session cookie, and if there is one at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I explain the problem here is that I need the script to work in every website. :)

Comment: @Alexandre - Well, you cannot. Session cookie name needs to be a parameter.

Comment: I added a paragraph at the end to say basically what Alvaro said.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks, I tought it would have been possible, that is why I asked the question cause I haven't found any solution. :)

Comment: Just to share information: Remember to disable HttpOnly for cookie if you go with this solution